# Does admob block apps which are compalsary uses vpn

Tags: android, admob, vpn

I have developed a browser app and this browser also provides VPN tool to connect VPN. Now i wanna monetise my browser app with AdMob but i heard that AdMob blocks clicks done by using VPN but my app always in VPN mode so would my account blocked?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Facebook Ads instead Ad mob ads or may be other ad networks. There are many of them.